# ZF1 sub-folder .htaccess rewrite issue

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting, apache2

I am facing some issue with .htaccess. I am using ZF1 for my project and trying to implement following scenario.

- http://project.local/user/event/index
- http://project.local/client-area/sample-event/en
- http://project.local/client-area/sample-event/en/register
- http://project.local/client-area/sample-event/en/detail

project.local is a virtual host pointing to public directory. First url is being served directly from controller where "user" is module name and "event" is controller name, for others urls "client-area" is a directory which exists in public directory of ZF1 and it contains .htaccess file. It contains following contents:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /user/event/detail/id/30 [NC,L]
```

When I try to access other urls, it redirects me to Error controller of default module but I want it to serve contents from Event controller in user module.

Please help in fixing this issue.

Answer (score 0):

From what I can see all requests are going to be sent to "/user/event/detail/id/30" I think what you are looking for is something more like:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^$ /user/event/detail/id/30 [NC.L]
RewriteRule ^.*$ index.php [NC,L]
```

I have not tested this, and I believe this can actually be solved in ZF using routes/setting the default route.